# Auto Size Buttons To Cover 1/3 of Screen Each

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink, size

I would like to make the following three buttons stretch to cover 100% of a my web page so that each button has about 1/3 of the page with a small gap between them.

Thanks in advance :)

```
<a style="padding: 6px 35px; background-color: #838383; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: -.2px; text-decoration: none; font-family: helvetica,arial,sans-serif; border-radius: 2px; font-size: 12px;" href="http://www.my-url.com">BUTTON 1</a>
&nbsp;
<a style="padding: 6px 35px; background-color: #636363; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: -.2px; text-decoration: none; font-family: helvetica,arial,sans-serif; border-radius: 2px; font-size: 12px;" href="http://www.my-url.com">BUTTON 2</a>
&nbsp;
<a style="padding: 6px 35px; background-color: #434343; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; letter-spacing: -.2px; text-decoration: none; font-family: helvetica,arial,sans-serif; border-radius: 2px; font-size: 12px;" href="http://www.my-url.com">BUTTON 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or without calc (a simpler version). Here is updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fk2naw3q/4/

```
a {
  float: left;
  width: 32.667%;
}
a + a{
  margin-left: 1%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, this is awesome - Just need to figure out how to put gaps between the buttons now.